# SQL oracle Developer error

Tags: create-table

```
CREATE TABLE person_details
( id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(100),
  age int,
  gender varchar(8),
  adult varchar(10),
  contact_no int,
  address varchar(255),
  pnr_number int
)

Error at Command Line:2 Column:15
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define the type of id field here:

```
( id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

Should be something like:

```
( id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     ^^^^
```

And make it as a primary key like

```
pnr_number int,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
```